# Unable to start rails server with any ruby versions

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently we're using ruby 2.2.3 but I've used rbenv to test different versions and for all of them when I attempt to run rails server, it gives me similar logs:

```
/Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/meta_request-0.7.3/lib/meta_request/railtie.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected '.' (SyntaxError)
      Rails.logger&.extend(LogInterceptor)
                    ^
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/meta_request-0.7.3/lib/meta_request.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/Desktop/Spectrio/apps/engage-ds-cms/app/config/application.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Here's /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/meta_request-0.7.3/lib/meta_request/railtie.rb before removing the '.' on line 20:

```
1. # frozen_string_literal: true
2. 
3. require 'rails/railtie'
4. 
5. module MetaRequest
6.   class Railtie < ::Rails::Railtie
7.     initializer 'meta_request.inject_middlewares' do |app|
8.       app.middleware.use Middlewares::MetaRequestHandler
9. 
10.       if defined? ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
11.         app.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions, Middlewares::Headers, app.config
12.       else
13.         app.middleware.use Middlewares::Headers, app.config
14.       end
15.  
16.       app.middleware.use Middlewares::AppRequestHandler
17.     end
18. 
19.     initializer 'meta_request.log_interceptor' do
20.       Rails.logger&.extend(LogInterceptor)
21.     end
22. 
23.     initializer 'meta_request.subscribe_to_notifications' do
24.       AppNotifications.subscribe
25.     end
26.   end
27. end
```

Then I removed the '.' from line 20 and got the following log:

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.1.14.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/meta_request-0.7.3/lib/meta_request/railtie.rb:20:in `block in <class:Railtie>': undefined method `&' for #<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x007fdbe355c460> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/Desktop/Spectrio/apps/engage-ds-cms/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/Desktop/Spectrio/apps/engage-ds-cms/app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/Desktop/Spectrio/apps/engage-ds-cms/app/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/Desktop/Spectrio/apps/engage-ds-cms/app/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.4/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.4/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.4/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:130:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:67:in `start'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Then I removed the '&' and added the '.' back and got this log:

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.1.14.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/airbrake-ruby-2.8.3/lib/airbrake-ruby/notifier.rb:32:in `initialize': :project_id is required (Airbrake::Error)
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/airbrake-ruby-2.8.3/lib/airbrake-ruby.rb:136:in `new'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/airbrake-ruby-2.8.3/lib/airbrake-ruby.rb:136:in `configure'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/Desktop/Spectrio/apps/engage-ds-cms/app/config/initializers/airbrake.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:420:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:419:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `call'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/Desktop/Spectrio/apps/engage-ds-cms/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/Desktop/Spectrio/apps/engage-ds-cms/app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/Desktop/Spectrio/apps/engage-ds-cms/app/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/Desktop/Spectrio/apps/engage-ds-cms/app/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.4/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.4/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.4/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:130:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:67:in `start'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/leon.shimizu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I tried to add the log from when I attempted it with ruby 2.4.6, 2.6.10, and 2.7.2 but I ran out of characters.

Also, I wanted to say that I'm currently debugging and researching these errors but I just wanted to ask to see if anyone has seen similar errors.

Also, if you need any more information about what version of certain gems or anything like that, please let me know and I'll add it.

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://api.rubygems.org'

##############################
# Rails and DB
##############################
gem 'rails', '4.1.14.2'
gem 'rack', '1.5.4'
gem 'rack-cors', '1.0.2', require: 'rack/cors'
gem "rake", '0.9.2.2'
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.20'
gem 'test-unit', '3.1.5'
gem 'rails-erd'


##############################
# Assets (formerly assets group)
##############################
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
gem "therubyracer", '0.12.2'
gem 'libv8', '3.16.14.13'
gem "less-rails", "3.0.0"
gem "railsstrap", "3.3.4"
gem "font-awesome-rails", "4.4.0.0"


##############################
# Environment
##############################
gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test, :production]


##############################
# I18n
##############################
gem 'http_accept_language', '2.0.0'
gem 'i18n-js', '3.0.2'


##############################
# Authentication
##############################
# devise is currently at version 4.3.0, but we can't
# upgrade to anything 4.0+ without upgrading to rails 4.
gem 'devise', '3.5.10'
# token authentication for API.
# current version is 1.0.0. we won't be able to upgrade
# until we can upgrade devise to 4.0.
gem 'devise-token_authenticatable', '0.4.10'
# used for password_regex in devise config.
# could this be moved to a validation callback on the user model
# since we are only using the regex capability?
# also, seems unmaintained. currently only supports up to rails 4.0.
gem 'devise_security_extension', '0.10.0'
gem 'cancan', '1.6.3'
gem 'omniauth', '1.4.2'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '4.0.0'
gem 'omniauth-twitter', '1.2.1'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '0.4.1'
gem 'omniauth-auth0'
gem 'doorkeeper', '3.1.0'


##############################
# API and Formatting
##############################
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
gem 'wicked_pdf', '0.9.8'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge', '~> 0.12.3.0'
gem 'speechmatics', '0.2.1'


##############################
# Model Behavior
##############################
gem 'actionpack-xml_parser', '1.0.2' # XML parameter parsing
gem 'activerecord-session_store', '1.0.0'
gem 'protected_attributes', '1.0.5'
gem 'rails-observers', '0.1.5'
gem 'sidekiq', '5.0.5'
gem 'sidetiq', '0.7.2'
gem 'ancestry', '2.0.0'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '4.0.0'
gem "audited-activerecord", '4.0.0'
gem 'geocoder', '1.6.1'
gem "rails_config", '0.2.5'
gem 'nokogiri', '1.6.0'
gem 'xml-simple', '1.1.5', :require => 'xmlsimple'
gem "rubyzip", "0.9.9"
gem 'google_timezone', '0.0.5'
# Included in Rails 4
#gem 'strong_parameters', '0.2.3'
gem 'acts_as_commentable', '4.0.2'
gem 'acts_as_list', '0.7.2'
gem 'ransack', '1.8.4'
gem 'ice_cube', '0.14.0'
gem 'simple_enum', '1.6.9' # can switch to active record enum when upgrade to rails 4


##############################
# Uploads
##############################
gem 'aws-sdk', '2.1.20'
gem 'carrierwave', '1.3.2'
gem 'carrierwave-aws', '1.2.0'
gem "mini_magick", "4.9.4"
gem 's3_direct_upload', git: 'https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload'
gem 'transloadit', '2.0.1'


##############################
# Caching
##############################
gem 'actionpack-page_caching', '~> 1.2.1'
gem 'redis-rails'
gem 'redis-store', '1.6.0'
gem 'redis-namespace', '1.6.0'
gem 'redmon', '0.0.8', :require => false


##############################
# Cron
##############################
gem 'whenever', "0.8.2", :require => false


##############################
# Monitoring
##############################
gem "airbrake", "7.2.1"
gem "airbrake-ruby", "2.8.3"
gem 'newrelic_rpm', '~> 3.6'
gem "oink", '0.10.1'

##############################
# Logging
##############################
gem 'apachelogregex', '0.1.0'
gem 'log4r', '1.1.9'


##############################
# UI
##############################
gem 'jquery-rails', "2.2.1"
gem "swfobject-rails", "2.0"
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap', "1.0.1"
gem "browser", "0.8.0"
gem "mobile-fu", "1.3.1"
gem "slim", "1.3.6"
gem "sinatra"


##############################
# EMAIL
##############################
gem "roadie", "3.0.3"
gem "roadie-rails", "1.0.4"


##############################
# Development/Linting
##############################
gem 'rubocop', '0.32.0', require: false

##############################
# Social
##############################
gem 'koala', '2.3.0' # Facebook
gem 'twitter', git: 'https://github.com/sferik/twitter', branch: 'master', ref: '60eb256'
gem 'google-api-client', '0.9'

##############################
# Util
##############################
gem 'json-compare'
gem 'chartkick', '3.0.2'

group :production do
end

group :test do
  gem 'factory_bot_rails', require: false
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5'
  gem 'shoulda', '~> 3.5', require: false
  gem "fakeredis", :require => "fakeredis/rspec"
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'test_after_commit', '1.1.0'
  gem "rspec_junit_formatter", "~> 0.4.1"
end

group :development do
  #gem 'rails4_upgrade', github: 'alindeman/rails4_upgrade'
  gem "query_reviewer"
  gem "capistrano", "2.15.6"
  gem "capistrano-ec2group"
  gem "capistrano-sidekiq"
  gem "net-ssh", "~> 2.7.0"
  gem 'quiet_assets', '~> 1.1.0'
  # enables use of rails panel extension https://github.com/dejan/rails_panel
  gem 'meta_request'
  # allows interactive debugging
  gem 'pry-remote'
  # file monitoring for tests
  gem 'ruby_dep', '~> 1.3.1'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '~> 4.7'
  gem 'brakeman', require: false
  gem 'bullet'
  gem "ruby-debug-ide", "~> 0.6.1"
  gem "debase", "~> 0.2.2"
end

gem "jwt", "~> 1.5"
gem "httparty", "~> 0.16.2"
gem "puma", "3.12.4"
gem "blazer", "~> 1.9"
gem 'actionpack', '4.1.14.2'
gem 'ffi', '1.9.24'
gem 'activerecord', '4.1.14.2'
gem 'mimemagic', github: 'mimemagicrb/mimemagic', ref: '01f92d86d15d85cfd0f20dabd025dcbd36a8a60f'
```

Comment: the safe navigator (&.) has been added in 2.3, so anything < 2.3 will not work.

What does the Gmefile/Gemfile.lock look like?

Comment: Hi @Pascal, thank you for getting back tome, I just added the Gemfile but wasn't able to add the Gemfile.lock because of the length limitation.

Comment: Rails 4.1 (quite old) was running on ruby >1.9.3 (with 2.0 recommended). 
The "meta_request" gem (and some others) are not versioned in the Gemfile and so the latest version is used, which causes trouble.

You could try with Ruby 2.0 and add a version to all the gems that do not have one. Pick a version that is from around February 29th 2016 (release date of the Rails version).

You can find the version info on rubygems.org (find the gem, then click on "all versions". Sample for "meta_request": https://rubygems.org/gems/meta_request/versions